# Writing user.get_profile() custom function which should create auth profile if there is not any

Tags: python, django

I am trying to write custom `get_profile()` function which should create user profile for users who are registered thru admin or any other way where `post_save` was not called.

How can I start this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you have a model to handle user profile like this:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    """Contains user profile fields not provided by User model"""
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    # Defined User profile fields like picture, phone, etc
```

So adding following line (maybe in your models.py after `UserProfile` model):

```
User.profile = property(lambda u: UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])
```

Allows access to the profile of a user (i.e. in templates: `{% user.profile.phone %}`) by creating it if not exists.

This is the way I solved in my site a problem like you describe.

Hope this helps

Comment: when will this line be called then?

Comment: It adds a property `profile`, to the User, so it called every time you access it, i.e. `theuser = User.objects.get(pk=1); print theuser.profile.<YOUR_PROFILE_FIELD>` or in template as I post in the answer, just use it ;)

Comment: so you shouldn't use `get_profile()` any more, this property replace it

Comment: Yes, it has been working in my site for almost a year

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit confused. Are you trying to let users create account and sign in? Then use django-registration which is easy and works out of the box.

Comment: no, some SEO people in the company are sometimes registered thru admin page and somehow they dont get profile created during save(). i dont know why.. thats why i wanted to check during get_profile() again if profile is there, if not i would create this..